# GLSL texture only works at (0,0)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I have created a texture and filled it with purple using OpenGL ES 3.1 on Android (using the NDK).
The problem is that texture lookup in the shader does not work as expected.

I create the texture like this:

```
glGenTextures(1, &mGLTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGLTexture);
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, textureSize.x, textureSize.y);

vector<GLubyte> img; int i = 0;
img.resize(4 * textureSize.x * textureSize.y);
for (unsigned x = 0; x < 64; ++x) {
    for (unsigned y = 0; y < 64; ++y) {
        img[i * 4 + 0] = 255;
        img[i * 4 + 1] = 0;
        img[i * 4 + 2] = 255;
        img[i * 4 + 3] = 255;
        // purple with full alpha
    }
}

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 
                64, 64,
                GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data());
```

No OpenGL errors are thrown during this process.

I then bind the texture:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mGLTexture);
glUniform1i(texLocation, 0); // got texLocation using glGetUniformLocation
```

Now, the problem occurs: In my shader, when I look up the texture only at (0,0), using `FragColor = texture(tex, vec2(0,0));` it works as expected, i.e things get painted purple.
For all other texture coordinates (e.g `vec2(0.5f,0.5f)`) I just get black everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried to set `GL_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_LINEAR` or `GL_NEAREST`? When no mipmaps are generated, interpolation modes that require mipmaps will fail.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither GL_NEAREST nor GL_LINEAR solve the problem.

Comment: You only set the first four values of img, since i = 0 in each iteration.

Comment: You maybe want to make that an answer, so I can accept? That was it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop only the first four elements of img are assigned. You might have forgotten to update the index variable i.

```
for (unsigned x = 0; x < 64; ++x) {
    for (unsigned y = 0; y < 64; ++y) {

        i = y * 64 + x;

        img[i * 4 + 0] = 255;
        img[i * 4 + 1] = 0;
        img[i * 4 + 2] = 255;
        img[i * 4 + 3] = 255;
        // purple with full alpha
    }
}
```